# system() changes char* argument address in a function in C

Tags: c, system

I have function, say:

```
int foo(char* a)
{
    printf("%d\n", (int)a);
    char cmd[] = "echo hello";
    system(cmd);
    printf("%d\n", (int)a);
}
```

in C code, and then I run it on linux; after doing so, I see that printf outputs are:

```
274351760
1853775725
```

I just confused so much! Any idea?! :|

Comment: `char cmd[] = "echo hello";`

Comment: @wildplasser not working!

Comment: How are you calling foo?

Comment: @JohnSibly this is just an abstract part of my huge codes! there are some backtraces to calling this function, but I am sure that before calling system() the value of `a` is valid, but after calling that it's not!

Comment: Using C4Droid (in Android), getting the same address (that is, not able to reproduce the question).

Comment: Using GCC 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 14.04, Linux 3.13), still can't reproduce.

Comment: @GenoChen C4Droid?! I'm just running a simple example on linux via C; no android-kind inserted! :)

Comment: @Arkku so I remove [10] to clarify my abstraction

Comment: @mohamadrezà Now your "abstraction" is useless because it doesn't have the problem described. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mohamadrezà I just have an Android phone currently :-D Then SSH into a server to test. C4Droid is a simple "IDE" for C in Android.

Comment: @GenoChen ok! got it!

Comment: @wildplasser you were right about your first comment! thx all! :)

Comment: The behavior described in the pre-edit question is clear evidence either that the lack of room for a null-character terminator in `char cmd[10] = "echo hello";`caused a problem or there is a problem elsewhere in the program (i.e., the code fragment shown is not the source of the problem; something else is corrupting memory or otherwise breaking the program).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works here:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(char* a)
{
    printf("%p\n", a);
    char cmd[] = "echo hello";
    system(cmd);
    printf("%p\n", a);
        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
foo("OMG");
return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

---

```
$ ./a.out
0x400718
hello
0x400718
```